# Applying styles to a dynamically-injected div via AJAX call (xhrGet)

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, dojo

Hey guys, I'm using the code below to retrieve updated content after receiving a "push" event from a server. The updated content is then used to replace the div/content that is already there.

**The problem I'm having is that none of my styles from my external stylesheet are applied to this new content.**

It makes sense to me why this would occur... but is there no way around this? I can apply styles dynamically, as I've done to an extent below, but it seems like there should be an easier way.

**Is there no way to have styles from an external stylesheet applied automatically to dynamically-loaded content?**

See code below:

```
loadContent = function(page, count) {
    var xhrArgs = {
        url: '/content/'+page+'/'+count+'/',
        handleAs: 'text',
        load: function(response) {
            dojo.byId('content').innerHTML = response;

            dojo.query('.dropdown').forEach(function(node, index, arr) {
                dojo.style(node, 'display', 'none'); // **This defaults to "display: none" in the stylesheet, but it's not applied until I do this**
            });
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.debug('error loading content');
        }
    };

    var deferred = dojo.xhrGet(xhrArgs);
};
```

Comment: Upon further examination, my problem was actually with dojo styles not being applied, because I had not run dojo.parser.parse() after updating the innerHTML attribute of the target div. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485631/dojo-and-ajax-initializing-html-with-the-dojotype-attr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Style sheets are applied dynamically already. If this doesn't happen then there is an error and possibly the new content doesn't have the tag names and attributes that your CSS applies on. So double check the returned data, and use Firebug to help you with that new content.

Comment: Hmm okay, I really thought that was the case, but I've checked everything... id names and class names all match up and the styles are applied just fine to the content that's NOT dynamic... at least it seems that's the case. I'll double-check; hopefully I'm just missing something right in front of me. Thanks.

Comment: Upon further examination, my problem was actually with dojo styles not being applied.